# MS SQL - выбрать каждому уникальному ID наиболее часто встречающееся значение другого поля

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день!
MS SQL. Есть таблица, уже сводная, в ней всего три поля: `ID`, `Brand`, `Title.`
И нужно выбрать для каждого `ID` наиболее часто встречающийся `Brand`.

То есть, например:

```
ID Brand Title
1  asd   asdasd
2  zxc   zxczxc
1  asd   asdasd
1  dfg   dfgdfg
```

В этом случае для `ID = 1` нужен `Brand =  asd` - потому что он повторяется дважды, а `dfg` только единожды.
 Количество не предсказуемо, может быть, что у какого-то `ID` будет всего 1 строка, а у какого-то 100 разных (или одинаковых).

Цикл по `ID` занимает слишком много времени, база большая. Есть ли более оптимальный способ?
Спасибо!

Comment: вы про функции ранжинования не слышали никогда?

Comment: и что вы понимаете под циклом по ID, как вы пытаетесь решить задачу вообще?

Comment: Спасибо, читаю про функции ранжирования. Раньше не нужно было общаться с базой сложнее, чем Select Update Join etc. А цикл - просто while (id < usercount), явный костыль, но больше ничего в голову не пришло.

Comment: для начала вам надо посчитать число title для каждого id-brand, в этом вам поможет группировка по этим полям и `count(title)`. затем потребуется отобрать пары id-brand с максимальным значением `count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Один из вариантов* решения сей задачи будет следующим.
Исходные данные:

```
declare @t table (id int, brand varchar(25), title varchar(255));

insert into @t values 
     (1, 'asd',  'asdasd')
    ,(2, 'zxc',  'zxczxc')
    ,(1, 'asd',  'asdasd')
    ,(1, 'dfg',  'dfgdfg');
```

Сначала необходимо подсчитать количество `title` для уникальных пар `id-brand`. Сделать это достаточно просто,  и для этого используется группировка и функция `count()`:

```
select id, brand, count(title) as cnt
from @t
group by id, brand;
```

что даст нам на выходе таблицу вида:

```
id          brand                     cnt
----------- ------------------------- -----------
1           asd                       2
1           dfg                       1
2           zxc                       1
```

Теперь необходимо отобрать такие id-brand, где значение cnt будет максимальным. С этой целью можно пронумеровать все строки среди уникальных `ID` в порядке убывания `cnt`, а затем взять их них строки с номером `1`. Для нумерации строк используется функция `row_number() over (...)`.  Чтобы строки нумеровались в группах по `id` необходимо добавить конструкцию `partition by id`. Чтобы номера раздавались по уменьшению числа `title` нужна инструкция `order by count(title) desc`.
В итоге запрос будет иметь вид:

```
select id, brand
    , count(title) as cnt
    , row_number() over (partition by id order by count(title) desc) as rn
from @t
group by id, brand
```

Результат запроса имеет следующий вид:

```
id          brand                     cnt         rn
----------- ------------------------- ----------- --------------------
1           asd                       2           1
1           dfg                       1           2
2           zxc                       1           1
```

Теперь осталось отбрать строки с `rn = 1`, а столбец `cnt` нам в принципе уже и не нужен. Тут мы можем воспользоваться общим табличным выражением (CTE) либо поздапросом:

```
with data as (
   select id, brand
        --, count(title) as cnt
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by count(title) desc) as rn
   from @t
   group by id, brand
)
select id, brand
from data 
where rn = 1
```

получая в результате список уникальных `ID` и значние `brand` для которых достигалось максимальное значение числа `title`.

```
id          brand
----------- -------------------------
1           asd
2           zxc
```

Comment: Спасибо! Начало у меня было примерно такое, а дальше не хватило знания матчасти. Может быть, заодно дадите ссылку на толковое объяснение курсоров?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это самый адекватный способ пробежаться по таблице, вкладывая соответствующие значения (теперь я полученное буду складывать в общую большую таблицу согласно id). Но я чего-то не понимаю - мой курсор прилежно бежит по бесконечному циклу, вставляя одно и то же значение в одно и то же место.

Comment: @user240459 а что там в курсорах объяснять то? сделали запрос, определили для него курсор, открыли, пока данные извлекаются - извлекайте, закрыли курсор, освободили ресурсы. принцип такой. а самая нормальная ссылка всегда будет вести вас на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191179(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Помещаем во временную таблицу количество записей для каждого уникального сочетания brand и id.

В подзапросе находим максимальное количество вхождений среди brand для каждого id и соединяем по этому количеству с временной таблицей.

```
insert into #temp_table 
select id, brand, count(*) as cnt from your_table
group by id, brand

select id,brand from #temp_table
(select id,max(cnt) as max_cnt from #temp_table 
group by id) as max_table
where max_table.id = #temp_table.id and max_table.max_cnt=#temp_table.cnt
```